# Unable to print a component multiple times using ReactToPrint

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to print the component `PrintStoreChallan` using `ReactToPrint` with different props by looping the array of data using map function. I want some kind of bulk printing functionality of challans with different data on a single button click.

A snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
            <ReactToPrint
            trigger={()=> <Button
            style={{ marginTop: '12px', marginLeft:'10px' }}
            className="challan-tab-button"
            onClick={() => {}
            >
            Print Store Challan
            </Button>
            }
            content={()=> this.printRef}
            />
            <div style=              
            {{visibility:'hidden',height:'0px',width:'0px'}}>
              {
                this.state.selectedRows.map((row) => {
                    <PrintStoreChallan
                    ref={this.setPrintRef} 
                    challanData = {row}          
                    /> 
                })

              }
            </div>
```

```
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.printRef = null

    this.setPrintRef = element => {
        this.printRef = element;
      };
```

The component `PrintStoreChallan` just contains a table with some data that is passed to it as a prop.

But while doing so I'm getting the error :

```
Refs are not available for stateless components. For "react-to-print" to work only Class based components can be printed.
```

I think that the content attribute of `ReactToPrint` is not getting reference of `PrintStoreChallan`component multiple times. But I'm unable to resolve this. Kindly help me with this.